# Angularjs: Interceptor redirection creates double rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am stuck with this strange behaviour. None of the Google hits seem to return any mention of a similar case so I am assuming that I am doing something seriously wrong.

My interceptor does react on the 401 status and redirects to the appropriate route but at the same time it renders the previous route too. So I have a very ugly flash of one template then the other. I am simply trying to test my authentication: if authenticated then render the table, otherwise render the login form. It does redirect to the login form but still flashes the table template for a fraction of a second.

```
angular.module('Basal', ['ngRoute', 'Basal.users'])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
  $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/tpl/table.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    }).
    when('/login', {
      templateUrl: '/tpl/login-form.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});


angular.module('Basal.users', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, getJson) {

  getJson.fetch(function (d){
    $scope.computers = d;
    });
})

.factory('getJson', function($http, $location) {
  return {
    fetch: function (c) {
      $http.get("/json")
        .success(function(data) {
          console.log("getJson: Success!");
          c(data);
        })
        .error(function() {
          console.log("getJson: Failure!");
        });
    }
  }
})

.factory('authInterceptor', function($q, $location) {
  return {
    'responseError': function(response) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        $location.path('/login');
      }
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  }
});
```

Now, when I hit '/' on the browser Angular does two requests on the background: one is to fetch the table template and insert it in to the view and the other is to get the JSON data.

On the server side I put session restriction only on the data request! The template is just a static file. To put restriction on the template I need to drag it through the server routing and this is not, I believe, how Angular does things. But if I do create server side route for the template and put session restriction on it then double rendering disappears.

I am confused about how this works. Fetching the template and fetching the data is done asynchronously in parallel. So while JSON request triggers 401 and redirects to the login template, the original table template is still going through and being rendered empty. Hence I get all the ugly double rendering. This is a race of some kind. How do I stop it? Maybe my interceptor is wrong? Isn't the Angular interceptor supposed to stop any further processing?

As a related issue, the `otherwise` function on the `$routeProvider` does not work either. If I put a non-existent URL, I get 404 from the server but Angular routing does not catch it. Is this how it is supposed to be? If a URL change happens in Angular and then I hit reload on the browser, I get an ugly 404 instead of a nice redirect. Am I supposed to handle 404 in an interceptor too? Then what is the point of `otherwise`?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into ng-cloak? It is used to prevent the flash of content that can appear when a template is being loaded: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: No, not yet. I am still learning and exploring ... I will have a look in a minute. Thank you.

Comment: No, `ng-cloak` does not solve the problem. I still get empty table template flash just before the redirection to the login template. Quickly reading about `ng-cloak` gave me the feeling that it is not what I am missing here. I'd think that it is something wrong with my interceptor ...

Comment: Okay, ng-cloak would've been easy!  I had all the same questions that it looks like you do when I first did auth in ng-apps.  Take a look at this blog: http://espeo.pl/authentication-in-angularjs-application/, it really helped me to put the pieces together.

Comment: did anyone ever figure this out?  It looks terrible when doing 401 auth

Comment: Try to put your `getJson.fetch` into a resolve on your route rule. By doing it, Angular will first try to resolve your dependency and then render the view. If you're not authenticated yet, the server will send a 401 error before try to get the template